# JPA and JPQL: NoResultException when selecting from multiple tables where one value is null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql, entitymanager

I'm using Java EE 6 and query a database using JPA's javax.persistence.Entitymanager. I have a JPQL query code snippet that looks like something like this:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("
    select A.propertyX, B.propertyY, C.propertyZ
    from TableA A, TableB B, TableC C
    where A.id = :id and B.id = A.id and C.type = B.type
");
query.setParameter("id", id);
Object[] result = (Object[]) query.getSingleResult();
```

Where propertyX/Y/X all are references to other entities. In my case, a matching row from TableA, TableB, and TableC all exist. For the matching rows, TableA.propertyX and TableB.propertyY hold values whereas TableC.propertyZ is null (and non-required).

I expect this to execute and return an Object[] array with values for the first two elements (propertyX and propertyY) and null for the third element (propertyZ).

However, when propertyZ is null, a NoResultException is thrown. If I change the data so that propertyZ is not null, the query executes and returns a value.

- Is this expected JPQL behavior?
- How can I ensure that my query will behave as I originally expected?

The obvious work-around is to select the entire root entity than any sub-property, e.g. 'C' rather than 'C.propertyZ', and then get the property out of the entity object. However, I'd like for this to work as I expect it to without doing so.

Answer (score 0):

If, for a given row in A and B, there is a row in C where C.type = B.type, but the propertyZ column for that row is null, then you are right that your query should return a record.

However if for that given row in A and B, there is no matching row in C where C.type = B.type, then your query will return no result. This has nothing to do with JPQL, but with SQL

If you want the latter case to still return a record with null in the propertyZ field, you need to use OUTER JOINs

HTH

Comment: As I wrote in my question: There **are** matching rows of all three tables.

But if C.propertyZ is null, the query fails. If C.propertyZ is **not** null, the query successfully returns something. Everything else remains the same. And C.propertyZ is not used in any of the query's conditions.

Comment: Not sure what could be causing it.. how different is the actual SQL query from this simplified version? Can you share the actual query?

Comment: My actual query is pretty similar to the one used here. I even modified it to look just like the one here and got the same outcome.